# Printing localStorage elements onto html page

Tags: javascript, html

Basically i'm wanting to capture a user's shopping basket and then print this information on a separate page. The user would be able to click on a button on the basket page which would take them to the new page (Which would have an invoice like structure showcasing their items, costs etc). Currently i have the following script running on the basket page.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName');

    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {
        var me = {name: itemName.textContent};
        localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(me));
    }
    else
    {
        // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
    }    
});
```

Which is accessing the following bit of html on the cart page

```
<!--START: itemnamelink--><a id="itemName" href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink-->
```

On the new page i'm creating where i want the information to be displayed in an invoice like fashion i have the following code.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    for(var key in items){
    if(items.hasOwnProperty(key)){

   document.getElementById("add").innerHTML +=  "name:" + "<br>" + items[key];
    }
}

});
</script>



<div id="add">

</div>
```

However i'm getting the following being printed which is not ideal. I eventually want a few more elements being printed. I think my problem is i'm printing the whole of the local storage so in my head it's just dumping it all on one line and i need to iterate through the storage and print each element separately.

```
  name:
  red chair black chair
```

Comment: Need some more of the HTML

Comment: If you get value into `innerHTML`, you should save it as HTML, not as a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to the objects you get from the storage.

```js
var json = '{"name":"black chair red chair"}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = obj.name;
```

```html
<div id='element'></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. This helped me work out my solution. I just need to make the lines break. I've updated my OP to showcase the new code and what i now get.

Comment: I think my new problem is, that it's pretty what it should. I need to somehow iterate through the local storage and print the elements separately if i can even do that.

Comment: @johndoi Yes, you need to iterate the array/object you got from the local storage.

     obj.forEach(function(element) {
        var item = document.createElement("span");
        var text = document.createTextNode(element.name);
        item.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById('element').appendChild(item); 
    });

Comment: I've updated my code with the code i'm now using. I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: I can't seem to get your code working but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeToLocalStorage(obj) {

        return localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(obj));
}

 function getFromLocalStorage() {

        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
}
writeToLocalStorage({ id: "2", cart: "item" });
var data = getFromLocalStorage();
console.log(data.id);
```

Then access with data.name